# circuit explanation for detecting different gases by mq2 with raspberry pi

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, circuit-design

I am able to get the readings from mq2 sensor but don't know how to detect different gases by it.

Can anyone help me in getting the circuit explanation of detecting different gases by using mq2 sensor when connected to raspberry pi?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to detect? A concentration of a known gas? Unknown gas? The kind of gas given a known concentration?

Comment: @Dmitry I am trying to find the concentration of different gases given in the mq2 datasheet. As u can see in this link http://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=165 . They are detecting LPG , CO and smoke with mq2 sensor when connected to Arduino. Since, I am new to electronics so i am not getting how to proceed the same with raspberry pi.

Comment: You didn't answer whether the gas you're trying to detect is know or not. However, the topic you refer to features a fart detection firwmare among other things, and that's the only application this sensor is good for without proper calibration. Don't worry, people don't fart CO or LPG.

Answer (score 1):

You can't differentiate between gases, if that's what you're asking. It has a single analog output, all it tells you is that some amount of some gas is present.

[The datasheet](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/3/3f/MQ-2.pdf) has a nice little chart which shows the variation in resistance due to a variety of gases.

Comment: Yes, i have checked it before  but isn't it mention in the datasheet about detecting concentration scope for different gases ? 
Please check this link http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=55780.0 . They have done it by connecting arduino to mq2 sensor but i m trying with raspberry pi and moreover i am not able to get the additional requirements for it .

Comment: That example doesn't detect different gases either.  It only makes a single measurement, and calls it CO concentration.  The concentration could be of ANY of the detectable gases, or any combination.

Comment: Also, I fail to see the application of this stuff: playing with toxic (CO) and explosive gases is not much fun, and it's not like you could rely on a random Arduino firmware for a gas alert. Read comment #10 from your link.

Comment: But even for getting the combination of gases, we need to convert the readings to ppm